# How does JavaFX 8 start the JavaFX Application thread in a nearly empty Application class?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Lets say, we have the following class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application
{
    public Test()
    {
        System.out.println("Constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("start");
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        System.out.println("main");
    }
}
```

It's derived from `Application` but it doesn't use any of its methods. Usually you start a JavaFX application by calling `launch(args)` in the main.

When I start this program the only output is "main", so the constructor and start aren't called, but the program doesn't terminate because there is a JavaFX Application thread running. But where does it come from?

I did some debugging and found out that the thread is started from the main thread before the main method runs. The stack trace starts with `NativeMethodAccessorImpl`.

To get even weirder: when I start the main method from a different class, the JavaFX Application thread isn't started:

```
public class Test2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test.main(args);
    }
}
```

So what kind of black magic is this?

Comment: Upvote for black magic.

Comment: In the second class, Test2, you have not added an extend Application in your original class declaration. So your runtime has no inkling that a JavaFX process is involved - it could be a main(.) method of any other kind of Java class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java uses different approaches to launch the two applications.

Try running the following code:

```
public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Class<?> actualMainClassTest = LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(true, 1, Test.class.getName());
        Class<?> actualMainClassTest2 = LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(true, 1, Test2.class.getName());

        System.out.println("Actual loaded main class for Test: " + actualMainClassTest.getName());
        System.out.println("Actual loaded main class for Test2: " + actualMainClassTest2.getName());
    }
}
```

The output is

- Actual loaded main class for Test: sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper
- Actual loaded main class for Test2: Test2

You can see that the actual loaded main class for the `Test2` class is `Test2`, but the loaded main class for
`Test` is `sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper`.

This happens because the Java launcher checks if the main class to be launched is a subclass of `javafx.application.Application`.
If it is, it loads the main method of `sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper` instead, which invokes a launcher method
for JavaFX applications (`com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl#launchApplication`).

This method is responsible for launching the JavaFX application. `Test#main` is called after the application is launched:

[image]

When `Test#main` is called by Test2, the FX launcher is not used because Test2 is not a subclass of `javafx.application.Application`.

Comment: So, that's a behaviour of java.exe and only works for javafx.application.Application?