# JavaFX Static vs non Static

Tags: java, javafx, static

Good day,

Why does JavaFX have a problem, if i create a static Label outside a method, but doesen't have the same problem with shapes like a sphere or a rectangle.

The following works just fine:

```
static Rectangle upperBorder = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
```

But this creates an exception:

```
static Label myScore = new Label("Test");
```

I have to create the Label the following way:

```
Label myScore = new Label("Test");
```

This is without the "static" keyword.

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at pong.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:24)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:550)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:512)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:87)
... 4 more
```

Comment: The error says that the JavaFX Toolkit has not been initialized, which is not directly related to using a `static` variable (though, imho, if you are making a UI control you are just doing things the wrong way anyway). Post a [MCVE] that generates the exception if you want someone to be able to figure out what is actually going wrong.

Comment: Did you extend `Application` and called `Application#launch` from the main method?

Comment: yes ,as proposed above , the error indicates that you are not starting the JavaFx application properly , it might not be related that you define smth `static`

Answer (score 2):

The error is most likely not caused by the `static` keyword.

Consider this simple test program:

```
public class Test {

   static Rectangle a   = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
   static Label     b   = new Label("b");

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   }
}
```

When launched it throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at Test.<clinit>(Test.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:550)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:512)
   at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:87)
   ... 1 more
```

This hints at the JavaFX Application Platform not being started. The error seems to disappear when the `static` keyword is removed in this example, but that is because the label `b` is not used in the code.

---

Launching the same class as a JavaFX Application ensures that the Platform is initialized before the first `Control` is created:

```
public class Test extends Application {

   static Rectangle a   = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
   static Label     b   = new Label("b");

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
}
```

The difference between `Rectangle` and `Label` in your code is that `Label` is a `Control` and `Rectangle` is not. `Label` can not be instantiated without a running JavaFX Platform.

Comment: That's interesting. `Control` has a static initializer that sets the user agent stylesheet (because controls require CSS; other nodes don't); that has to happen on the FX Application Thread and so the first example generates an exception because the platform is not started. But in the second example, how does the platform get started before the `Label` is created? I always assumed that `launch()` started it; but surely the `Label` it created in this example before `launch()` is called.

Comment: @James_D Yes, it is interesting. I am still looking into it. I know that a class extending Application [gets launched by LaucherHelper$FXHelper.main](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28328284/1288408). This helper must somehow be responsible for calling `startup` in `PlatformImpl`.

Comment: But that is called from the `launch` method, by which time the `Label` has already successfully been created (you can do a `System.out.println(b);` *before* the `launch()` call in `main()`...).  Seems like magic...

Comment: @James_D Steeping through the code, apparently `PlatformImpl.startup` is called by the launcher _before_ the label is created, followed by `Application.launch`. The platform is started by the launcher before any other action takes place: Platform started -> Label created -> Application launched.

Comment: Clearly, otherwise it wouldn't work :). But how? I don't see any code in [`Application`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/graphics/src/main/java/javafx/application/Application.java) that could cause this to happen. Kind of academic, but just quite interesting...

Comment: Ah, OK. I think this is done by the Oracle JRE startup mechanism. It checks if the main class (specified on the command line or by a manifest in a jar file) is a subclass of `Application` and starts the JavaFX platform if so. If you create another class with a `main` method that just delegates to `Test.main(...)` you see the exception again.

Comment: @James_D I looked into it a bit for my answer on the other question linked in the comments, but I don't remember much. What I learned was that the launcher acts as a kind of preprocessor for FX application launches. For JavaFX applications, it delegates to an FX launcher that starts the FX Platform first of all.