# JavaFX issue with static keyword; with Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Tags: java, javafx, static

Good day,

When I run this Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class mcve extends Application {

    static Label myScore = new Label("Test");
    static Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,10,10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        myScore.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        myScore.setLayoutY(20);
        myScore.setLayoutX(200);
        myScore.setFont(new Font("Arial", 30));
        myScore.setText("0");
        rect.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        final Group group = new Group(myScore,rect);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 500, 500, Color.BLACK);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

it creates the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at mcve.<clinit>(mcve.java:11)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:550)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:512)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:87)
... 4 more
```

However if I remove the static keyword before Label at the top, the code runs just fine.

My question is: Why does the error occur when creating a static Label but not a static Rectangle? I want the Label to be static and not an object of a class.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions of existing questions simply to add more information. If you want to add more detail, you should edit your [existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792808/javafx-static-vs-non-static). You have now divided this discussion into two parallel threads.

Comment: "I want the label to be static". Why? There is no valid use case for this imho.

Comment: I tested this code, verbatim, and it actually ran just fine on my platform (JDK  8 u71, OSX 10.11.3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the error occur when creating a `static Label` but not a `static Rectangle`?

Essentially, this is a matter of initialization order. The UI platform needs to be properly initialized when creating `Node` objects. Potentially, it could also happen with a `Rectangle`, but most likely a `Label` (which is a `Control`) relies even more on a properly initialized platform. In this particular case, the difference is that `Shape` objects do not require `CSS`, while `Control` objects do. This causes the platform methods to be called as seen in the stack trace, at a point when the toolkit is not yet initialized.

- The `static` class member is initialized when `class mvce` is loaded. This is done before the `main()` method is called, and hence before the `launch()` method is called. The platform is not initialized yet at this point.
- The non-static member, on the other side, is initialized when `class mvce` is instantiated. The `class mvce` is instantiated internally by the `launch()` method, **after** the toolkit has been properly initialized.

Also, there is usually no reason to use static references. Just use a member.

Comment: Controls require CSS, so `Control` has a static initializer that effectively calls `Application.setUserAgentStylesheet()`, which delegates to the FX Application Thread. This generates the exception for me if I instantiate a control in a plain vanilla Java class (but not in an `Application` subclass as in the OP's code). `Rectangle` does not require CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. My question is answerd!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to just declare the static label, but instanciate and set it later on in the start() method? This should work, too.